# Bigpipe module override the form action url in drupal9

Tags: drupal-8

I am using Drupal9 with site studio feature. enabled multi-site configuration. all user forms like registration, forgot password, resetpassword form action should have current url but it is have some random text 
when try to submit the form, it gets redirected to page not found error.
form action commented below

Comment: <form class="user-pass" data-drupal-selector="user-pass" action="form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM" method="post" id="user-pass" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-drupal-form-fields="edit-name,edit-submit">